# Skilled Worker Visa UK: working occasionally in the EU

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa, eu-citizens

Does a UK Skilled Worker Visa confer any formal status for the holder occasionally traveling to the EU to work?

Would it cause any legal trouble to try?

Comment: Are you asking from the perspective of the UK or the EU? Or both? A UK work visa doesn’t entitle its holder to travel to, or work in, the EU.

Comment: @Traveller but I am an EU citizen

Comment: @Gergely but it does not say that in your question. Would your travel to the EU to work be for the same employer as in the UK?

Comment: No, it would be under my limited company.

Comment: Are you worried that working in the EU would somehow get you in trouble with the UK authorities?  Why do think they would care?

Comment: @Gergely If you want a meaningful answer you should edit your question to include all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

From [Skilled Worker visa - Taking on additional work](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa/second-job)

> You can do additional paid work on this visa as long as you’re still doing the job you’re being sponsored for. You can also do unpaid voluntary work.
>
> You can work up to 20 hours a week in a job that’s either:
>
> - in the same occupation code and at the same level as your main job
> - in a shortage occupation

> If you’ll be working more than 20 hours a week or in a different occupation code
>
> - You’ll need to apply to update your visa so that you’re being sponsored to do both jobs.

I presume the above rules relate to UK-based work not ad hoc work in the EU, however it seems logical that they would apply to you if your limited company is incorporated in the UK. IANAL, if I were you I would get qualified advice.

Comment: Qualified advice: 290£ per hour.

Comment: @Gergely Think of it as an investment of a few hours’ worth of your income. You would be paying to get peace of mind that what you want to do won’t lead to your UK visa being cancelled